# Windows Azure ServiceBus Relay clarification

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

Could some one Azure Service Bus expert help me with queries below?

1. When does these TCP ports gets used 9350 to 9354? Any communication between Azure Service Bus Relay and on-premise WCF Service?
2. If we use webHttpRelayBinding, then Client to Service Bus End Point request happens via HTTPS and from SB to WCF Service via TCP?
3. If we use tcpRelayBinding then Client to SB and SB to WCF Service happens over TCP?
4. Is it possible to use Hybrid Connection for webHTTPRelayBinding as we are noticing slow response time?
5. Is it fair to assume that tcpRelayBinding is always faster than webHTTPRelay Binding?
6. Is it fair to assume that communication between SB and WCF Service (Onpremise) always happens on TCP only?

Answer (score 1):

1) The TCP ports get used when the listener interacts with Service Bus.

2) You can specify the connection type for SB -> on premise service by setting `ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Http`. The default setting is `ConnectivityMode.AutoDetect`, which will attempt to use TCP first.

3) Similar to 2.

4) Not too sure on this ATM.

5) I believe it is faster.

6) Nope, if `AutoDetect` is the connectivity mode, the communication can happen via HTTP.